# How do you spell explicitly my last name (Musiał)?

Tags: orthography

I need to know how I can spell my Polish last name, Musiał, for my future interviews. (soon :>)

- M as Margarita
- U as ..?
- S as
- I as
- A as
- Ł as - what about that character? Should i replace it by L, for convenience?

  ("Musiał" in Polish language means "he has", for example "On musiał to zrobić" in English will be "He must do it". So I maybe translate my last name to "he has" or something?)

Comment: Mike, Uniform, Sierra, India, Alpha, Lima-with-bar. [NATO Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)

Comment: Where are you?  If in the US you need to pick a spelling of your name which uses only "Roman" characters (possibly with the Spanish "enya" added).

Comment: Currently in Poland, but I will need explicit spelling for Great Britian standards. Besides this, I don't know why I can't upvote your comments.

Comment: @HotLicks What on earth's wrong with his keeping *Musial*. It is infinitely more pronounceable than most Polish surnames! But I loathe the international phonetic alphabet and always make up my own. I would probably say: M for Mustapha, U for Ulysses, S for Sammy, I for india, A for Archibald, and L for Lucy. If you can come up with any funny ones, they will always be appreciated in Britain.

Comment: If your're in the US, spell it: M U S I A L - Like "Stan the Man" - (Stanisław Franciszek Musial) Baseball Hall-of-Famer.  (If anyone asks... you 'think he's a distant cousin'.)

Comment: @WS2 - Certainly "MUSIAL" is perfectly fine, if that suits the OP.  But I have no idea how that "L-bar" is pronounced, and for all I know it would make more sense to replace it with a "K" or some such.

Comment: It's pronounced [w].

Comment: @WS2, isn't the point of "Alpha, Bravo, Charlie ..." that it's a *standard*, which makes it easier for listeners, knowing which 26 words to expect?

Comment: @HotLicks I think you’re confused there. [Enya is Irish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enya), not Spanish. ;-)

Comment: Last I checked, translation questions were off-topic here. This isn't exactly translation, but I imagine the same reasoning applies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar case with my second name containing a Czech character (Č). I just write it as a C, however people recognize if I spell it with **ch** or **cz** (because cz itself used to represent Č, which was defined later, and ch as in chocolate is how the czech č sounds).

I suggest you spell it as M U S I A L, or if the spelling does not look weird, spell in more letters how the Ł sounds. I would use that in databases with problems with these kinds of letters, but on paper or word, the Ł is okay, because it still looks well pronounciable.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki: Ł](http://%20Wiki)

> In countries where Ł is not available, basic L is used instead. Thus, the surname Małecki would be spelled Malecki in a foreign country. Similarly, the stroke is sometimes omitted on the internet, as may happen with all diacritic-enhanced letters. Leaving out the diacritic does not impede communication for native speakers, but it may be confusing for those learning Polish.